# Разбиение строк на подстроки в Go

Tags: golang

Здравствуйте!

Я начинаю изучать Google Go. Вопрос такой. Если есть строка

```
до := "один, два, три"
```

как из этой строки получить срез

```
после := []string{ "один", "два", "три" }
```

Одним словом, как разбить строчку на подстрочки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На сайте языка Go есть [страница](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/), посвященная пакету обработки строк. Функция разбиения - Split.

Comment: после := strings.Split(до, ", ", -1)